# как правильно пишется: сейчас одного без другого, как правило, не бывает или одних без других

Tags: грамотная-речь

как правильно пишется: сейчас одного без другого, как правило, не бывает или одних без других

Comment: Сейчас одного без другого (или одних без других), как правило, не бывает. Сейчас одного без другого, или одних без других, как правило, не бывает.